# Why can't I reference XMLSchema as https?

Tags: xml, xsd

Trying to work around a restriction that is beyond my control.  We need to do schema validation as part of our work but nothing in the system is allowed to access http only https.  I tried changing the schema xmlns to be https in XMLSpy but that doesn't validate despite me being able to see it in a browser when I go to https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

I want to do this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

-- schema stuff --

</xs:schema>
```

Instead of this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

-- schema stuff --

</xs:schema>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a namespace URI, not a URL. No-one ever fetches anything at that location. The namespace is defined in the specs as `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` and you can't change it. If someone is reporting a security problem with this, they are mistaken and need to refine their rules.

Comment: Thanks, after doing some reading I came to the same conclusion.  This page explains it well:  https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/692

Comment: *No-one ever fetches anything at that location.* Well, the web server logs at that location probably prove people do fetch the page at that URL, but, right, that's not the point of a namespace URI.   We've answered that question many times before, however -- see the duplicate links.